# Reading more than 200M rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read a csv file that has more than 200M rows and the data look like this:

| id_1 | date | id_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hf23R | 01-01-2005 | M9R34 |

There is no null in the data and there is no special character i tried read it the basic way but it crash my computer every time i run the code i cannot do any analysis on it or anything so is there is a way to read via panda in a sufficient way!!

Here is how i read it!

```
  import pandas as pd
   path = "data.csv"
  df = pd.read_csv(path)
```

Comment: I guess it's memory problem.
Have you tried those solutions?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas

Comment: Thank you so much i will try it now

Comment: Is there an error message?  Does the computer just lock up?  Please clarify what you mean "crash my computer".

Comment: There was no error in the code but i got a blue screen and it says there was a problem and the computer need to restart.

Comment: I used the dask and it works perfectly thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I used the dask and it works perfectly

```
 import dask.dataframe as dd

 df = dd.read_csv('data.csv')
```